# Import JSON data not working in Azure ML studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am not able to ingest JSON data in Azure ML designers import data component. Is there any way to do it

Am i missing something?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **tabular data** can be ingested in Import data component.

**Workaround:**

You can use Azure data factory to convert json to structured data. Then you can try to import data in azure ml studio’s import data component.

There are following rules while importing data

**a.**  All data files must have the same schema(columns and column names)

**b.**   To get all files in folder given path should be folder_name/**

**c.**  Data files must be encoded in unicode-8.

When import completes, right-click the output dataset and select Visualize to see if the data was imported successfully.